# Insert into SQL table field not ordered

Tags: c#, sql, insert

I have this SQL table:

> Employee ( Id, Name, Address, Tel)

and I want to execute SQL queries without respecting the indicated order, something like this:

```
Insert Into Employee (Tel, name, Id, Address) 
Values (555621, "Jihen", 10236, "21 Cranberry street")
```

Am I allowed to do this?

Comment: Short answer is yes.  It doesn't matter what order you insert, so long as the values are in the matching order of your insert.

Comment: The Sql you posted yourself will do exactly what you suggest.  Did you even try it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes - so long as you specify the order explicitly (as you have shown) in both parts of the statement

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is allowed. The order in your `INSERT` query compared to the column order in the table is not signficant.

However, you **must** ensure the order of column names in your query matches the order that the values are supplied in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can... Have you tried it though?